# unable to deploy UWP app built from website

Tags: visual-studio, web, visual-c++, uwp

I'm trying to convert my website into an UWP application to enable me to upload it into microsoft store. I found out an article: 'https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/convert-web-application-to-universal-windows-platform-app-in-visual-studio-2017/' which helped me to build the uwp app from my website using visual studio 2019 successfully.
I followed the steps listed below to create my UWP app

Step 1:
I created a new project and selected Blank APP (Universal Windows) in Windows Universal section of JavaScript templates and chose windows 10 as target version

Step 2:
Opened the package.appmanifest > Application Tab and changed entry point to my web url:https://mbracecloud.com

Step 3:
Opened Content URI tab and pasted web url:mbracecloud.com in URI field.

Step 4:
Then i hit the local machine build button, which built the app successfully and launched it within minutes.

But the app showed a blank page instead of opening my website.

I do not know where i'm going wrong ?

Comment: Could you provide the detail steps that how do you convert website into uwp app?

Comment: added the necessary details for better understanding of my problem

Comment: So the problem only occurs in VS 2019? I tried your app within VS2017, it could open above website.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be the case, i can show you the screenshot

Comment: VS 2019 has removed WinJs Template. please create and build the with VS 2017

Comment: Agreed, proceeding with vs 2017 installation

Comment: Ok,May I convert above as an answer for this thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> which helped me to build the uwp app from my website using visual studio 2019 successfully.

During the testing, make WinJS blank app and edit `package.appmanifest` changed entry point with website address, then add `Content URI`. And it works well.
Visual Studio 2019 has removed WinJs Template. Please create and build the with VS 2017. And for this scenario we suggest you use [PWA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/progressive-web-apps-chromium/) to replace WinJS blank app template.